# Method references to multidimensional arrays in Java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, language-lawyer, method-reference

In Java we may create `IntFunction<String[]>` from 1D array constructor reference:

```
    // both do the same thing
    IntFunction<String[]> createArrayL = size -> new String[size];
    IntFunction<String[]> createArrayMR = String[]::new;
```

Now I wonder why we cannot do this with a 2D array:

```
    BiFunction<Integer, Integer, String[][]> createArray2DL = 
            (rows, cols) -> new String[rows][cols];

    // error:
    BiFunction<Integer, Integer, String[][]> createArray2DMR =
            String[][]::new;
```

Of course we may write:

```
    IntFunction<String[][]> createArray2DInvalidL = String[][]::new;
    System.out.println(createArray2DInvalidL.apply(3)[0]); // prints null
```

but this will behave differently than:

```
    new String[3][3]
```

because row arrays will not be initialized.

So my question is: why `String[][]::new` doesn't work for 2D arrays (for me it looks like an inconsistency in language design)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quite an interesting case indeed.

The problem is that `String[][]::new` is a function with an arity of 1(it's a constructor of an array of arrays) and can't be treated as a BiFunction(arity of 2) and your example `new String[3][3]` has two parameters instead of one.

In this case,
`createArray2DInvalidL.apply(3)`
is equal to calling `new String[3][];`

What you might be looking for is:

`IntFunction<String[][]> createArray2D = n -> new String[n][n];`

Dimensions don't need to have equal lengths and it sounds like a pretty reasonable assumption.

http://4comprehension.com/multidimensional-arrays-vs-method-references/

Comment: and why `BiFunction<Integer, Integer, String[][]> createArray2DL = (a,b) -> String[][]::new;` produce an error ??

Comment: @user43968 because in your lambda expression you're returning another function 
```BiFunction<Integer, Integer, IntFunction<String[][]>> createArray2DL = (a, b) -> String[][]::new;```

Answer (score 1):

There is no inconsistency here. If you write a statement like

```
IntFunction<ElementType[]> f = ElementType[]::new;
```

you create a function whose evaluation will return a new array with each entry being capable of holding a reference of `ElementType`, initialized to `null`. This doesn’t change, when you use `String[]` for `ElementType`.

But it also has been addressed explicitly in [The Java Language Specification, §15.13.3. Run-Time Evaluation of Method References](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.3-400-E):

> If the form is *Type[]<sup>k</sup>* :: new (*k* ≥ 1), then the body of the invocation method has the same effect as an array creation expression of the form new *Type [ size ] []<sup>k-1</sup>*, where *size* is the invocation method’s single parameter. (The notation *[]<sup>k</sup>* indicates a sequence of *k* bracket pairs.)

There is no support for a rectangular multi-dimensional array creation method reference, most likely, because there is no actual use case that acted as a driving force. The one-dimensional array creation expression can be used together with `Stream.toArray(…)`, allowing a more concise syntax than the equivalent lambda expression, despite there is no special support in the underlying architecture, i.e. `int[]::new` produces exactly the same compiled code as `intArg -> new int[intArg]`. There is no similar use case for a two (or even more) dimensional array creation, so there isn’t even a similar functional interface for a function consuming two or more `int` value and producing a reference type result.

Comment: My point was that since in Java you may create 2d array by `new Element[5][6]` or by `new Element[5][]` (of course in the first case compiler will also allocate rows for me) then Java should allow the same with constructor reference. I am puzzled because if compiler can allocate rows in `new X[a][b]` expression then why not in `X[][]::new` - event if that would mean to generate synthetic lambda expression.

Comment: Nobody says that it wouldn’t be possible to write a compiler being capable of generating such code. But the language designers did not add a syntax for it. The syntax for the one dimensional array creation method reference behaves consistent, even if the element type is an array itself. A hypothetical rectangular multi-dimensional array creation method reference syntax has to differ from that, as it would not be acceptable if `X[][]::new` sometimes creates subarrays and sometimes not. There would be not much advantage of the additional syntax compared to an equivalent lambda expression.